# how can I convert a json object and pass to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am using the Kucoin api to get all the tickers that they currently offer. I then want to pass parts of the JSON object to a pandas dataframe. One ticker JSON object (of hundreds) looks like this:

```
data = {
    "time":1602832092060,
    "ticker":[
        {
            "symbol": "BTC-USDT",
            "symbolName":"BTC-USDT",
            "buy": "11328.9",
            "sell": "11329",
            "changeRate": "-0.0055",
            "changePrice": "-63.6",
            "high": "11610",
            "low": "11200",
            "vol": "2282.70993217",
            "volValue": "25984946.157790431",
            "last": "11328.9",
            "averagePrice": "11360.66065903",
            "takerFeeRate": "0.001",
            "makerFeeRate": "0.001",
            "takerCoefficient": "1",
            "makerCoefficient": "1"
        }
    ]

 ..... }
```

I want to make a datframe that includes some but not all of the "columns". Namely: `symbol`, `buy`, `sell`, `high`, `low`, `averagePrice`

I have tried:

```
pd.to_json
pd.json_normalize
```

I have tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['ticker'][0])
```

Nothing works. I get various different error messages quoting "scalar values", lack of index.

I shall be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_normalize` with `record_path` and `meta` parameters:

```
out = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='ticker', meta='time')[['time', 'symbol', 'buy', 'sell', 'high', 'low', 'averagePrice']]
```

Output:

```
            time    symbol      buy   sell   high    low    averagePrice
0  1602832092060  BTC-USDT  11328.9  11329  11610  11200  11360.66065903
```